# How can I consolidate this jquery code

Tags: jquery

I have navigation elements that add a class to the clicked link, and removes the class from the remaining links. How can I consolidate this easily into one function that recognizes which link is clicked and removes the class from the remaining links (or active link)

Heres code for one link - trying to avoid this for each link:

```
$("#work").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#about").removeClass('active');
    $("#testimonial").removeClass('active');
    $("#instruction").removeClass('active');
    $("#blog").removeClass('active');
    $("#contact").removeClass('active');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Give them a common class, and use it. `$('.all_of_em').click(func...` Then `$('.active').removeClass('active'); $(this).addCla...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but how about:

```
function mark_active() {
  $('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
}
$("#work, #about, #testimonial, #instruction, #blog, #contact").click(mark_active);
```

Comment: you should cache your jQuery objects

Comment: also, be aware that `#work, #about, #testimonial, #instruction, #blog, #contact` selector is not that optimal :/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem...

```
var allYourLinks = $("someSelector");

allYourLinks.click(function () {
    // remove all active class
    allYourLinks.removeClass('active');
    // add the class to the clicked link
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // even better than .addClass call is:
    this.className += " active";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add a class to all links of the group, e.g. "activeGroup".

Than use the following function:

```
var activeGroupClick = function(){
  $('.activeGroup').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
}

$('.activeGroup').click(activeGroupClick);
```

Comment: you should cache the `$('.activeGroup')` result

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what are you trying to do, But I think this might help:

```
var links = $('a');
links.click(function () {
    links.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: you should cache the `$("a")` call

Answer (score 0):

Considering, all the links are `<a>` and inside a parent lets say `#menu`.

```
var allchild = $("#menu").children("a");
allchild.click(function () {
   allchild.removeClass('active'); //remove the classes from all the menus
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Even if not

```
$("#work").click(function () {
    $("#work, #about, #testimonial, #instruction, #blog, #contact").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: you should cache your selection

Comment: nice, but what's the difference between `$("#menu").children("a")` and `$("a")` ?

Comment: @pomeh, $("a") gets every link in the page, where as $("#menu").children("a") gets only inside of #menu

Comment: well, I know the difference but I meant that in your example you should use the `children` form for the click handler, what you've done right now. Then, you could write `allchild.click(...)` instead of doing the selection twice :)

Comment: @pomeh, that was such a nice suggestion. Thanks, Updated my answer